# How to disable night?

Tags: factorio

How can I disable night, i.e. the night portion of the day/night cycle?

I'd like to play in eternal daylight.

I didn't notice any relevant settings when creating a new game and I'd like to avoid mods if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/factorio/comments/6vcwif/is_there_anyway_to_disable_night_time/dlz8zhu/) on a post asking the same thing on the Factorio subreddit:

> Open the console (by default it's the <kbd>`</kbd> key) and type:
>
> ```
> /c game.surfaces[1].always_day=true
> ```
>
> If achievements are enabled on your game, you'll get a warning that they will be disabled, and you'll have to enter it again.